Allowable options for Chalcedonian understanding of Jesus's dual will at Gethsemane
Dual wills of Jesus, as human and as God, are on full display in the Synoptic gospels' account of Jesus's suffering and temptation at Gethsemane.  Let's first review how each gospel recounts the story:

Matthew 26:38-39:

Then saith he unto them, My soul is exceeding sorrowful, even unto death: tarry ye here, and watch with me.  And he went a little farther, and fell on his face, and prayed, saying, O my Father, if it be possible, let this cup pass from me: nevertheless not as I will, but as thou wilt. (KJV)


Then he said to them, “My soul is very sorrowful, even to death; remain here, and watch with me.” And going a little farther he fell on his face and prayed, saying, “My Father, if it be possible, let this cup pass from me; nevertheless, not as I will, but as you will.” (ESV)


Mark 14:34-36:

And saith unto them, My soul is exceeding sorrowful unto death: tarry ye here, and watch. And he went forward a little, and fell on the ground, and prayed that, if it were possible, the hour might pass from him. And he said, Abba, Father, all things are possible unto thee; take away this cup from me: nevertheless not what I will, but what thou wilt. (KJV)


And he said to them, “My soul is very sorrowful, even to death. Remain here and watch.” And going a little farther, he fell on the ground and prayed that, if it were possible, the hour might pass from him. And he said, “Abba, Father, all things are possible for you. Remove this cup from me. Yet not what I will, but what you will.”  (ESV)


Luke 22:42-45:

Saying, Father, if thou be willing, remove this cup from me: nevertheless not my will, but thine, be done. And there appeared an angel unto him from heaven, strengthening him. And being in an agony he prayed more earnestly: and his sweat was as it were great drops of blood falling down to the ground. And when he rose up from prayer, and was come to his disciples, he found them sleeping for sorrow, (KJV)


saying, “Father, if you are willing, remove this cup from me. Nevertheless, not my will, but yours, be done.” And there appeared to him an angel from heaven, strengthening him. And being in agony he prayed more earnestly; and his sweat became like great drops of blood falling down to the ground.  And when he rose from prayer, he came to the disciples and found them sleeping for sorrow, (ESV)



Reading between the lines, it's obvious there is temptation, sorrow, fear, and surrender within the human soul of Jesus and we (who are called to take up our cross) can relate.  Luke also added that an angel appeared to strengthen Jesus and how the disciples were also sorrowful.
Next, let's review several obvious doctrinal implications applicable to this episode to limit allowed interpretations:

As God Jesus never ceases to want to save us by being the Passover Lamb to "take away the sins of the world" (John 1:29).
Chalcedonian definition allows us to reconcile this apparent ambivalence of wills at Gethsemane by interpreting the above passages that as Man Jesus is struggling to align his human will with his own Trinitarian will while remaining sinless since Jesus managed to overcome all his natural feelings to not deviate from the Trinitarian mission to go through with the Divine plan.
Jesus who is also fully God must have continually loves Himself immanently in Jesus, never ceasing to do so during the whole Passion, even at the cross when Jesus cried "Eli, Eli, lema sabachthani?" (!)  We can safely assume that Jesus as Man could do perfectly the commandment "love your neighbor as yourself" partly because in his human consciousness he feels and trusts that he is so fully loved by God.

So far so good.  My question has to do with characterizing what's going on in Jesus's human mind and will so that it can help us to be more like Jesus.  For example, in our own walk of discipleship, it's common to distinguish "surrender" from "submission" which for the purpose of this question, I'm defining the two terms as follows:

"submission" as negation of will like a soldier doing something that he may not agree personally; this has been characterized by obedience out of slavish mentality or out of fear.  Colloquially we say: "I do it simply because you told me to".  At best, although it is done like a robot, I am still open to doing it with better motivation in the future.
"surrender" implies aligning one's will with another's thus with some level of agreement; this can be characterized by obedience out of trust mentality (like children) and by love.  Colloquially we say: "I do it as you asked me to, although I need help in uniting my will with your perfect loving will because of .... (you name it)".  So even though we don't feel like forgiving enemies, surrendering our selfishness to love difficult people, or dying as a martyr, because we always want to be yoked with Jesus (i.e. tagging along) we then rely on his Holy Spirit (Love) to strengthen us in uniting in love our will with Jesus's will.

It is obvious that as children of God we are asked to "surrender", not to "submit" (per definitions above).  Because Jesus is our model, I think conceiving Jesus's struggle at Gethsemane as a "submission" (negating will) rather than as a "surrendering" (uniting in love) is out of bound.  Is this true?  The difficulty seems to be textual: those who insist on literal meaning may interpret Jesus's "not as I will, but as you will" and the language "deny himself/ lose his life" (Matt 16:24-25) as a "submission", negating his human will.  But I think this is abhorrent, since there is no virtue in mere submission without love.  Rather, we should see Jesus's sinless internal struggle episode at Gethsemane as a revelation of how hard it is to love, that even Jesus, while operating in his human nature, had to struggle to align his human will with His own revealed divine will, as a model for us to unite in love our own will with our Father's will that is revealed to us in graced discernment.  This is in contrast to acting as a slave / soldier who simply executes what Scriptures command us to do.
How can the Trinity doctrine and Chalcedonian definition help us here?  My question is very specific: Formally & philosophically, what kinds of interaction of the 2 wills are allowed within the Chalcedonian orthodoxy? What are some examples of interaction that are out of bound?

You'd know my two brain hemisphere analogy already. I think the answer is that the interactions are mystical and beyond our understanding... There is no true parallel to the hypostatic union within the creation, only partial analogies. So nothing else interact like Jesus's two natures do.

@curiousdannii Yes, I re-read your answer yesterday. I'm being more optimistic, holding out a candle for someone to help me gain more understanding though, possibly Fr. Thomas J. White through his recent book book on Christology. In the meantime, any feedback to improve the question would be welcome.

@curiousdannii Another promising resource, a lecture by Eleonore Stump on The Two Natures of Christ.  Seems quite technical, but haven't watched it.  35 minutes long, with about 1 hour Q&A.
